# What to do if keyboard doesn't have a straight Fn key lock?

Tags: windows-7, laptop, keyboard, keyboard-shortcuts, keyboard-layout

I have an external keyboard for my laptop. <kbd>Fn</kbd> key used to work perfectly fine but I think I pressed a combination that enabled <kbd>Fn</kbd> key lock. Keyboard doesn't have a button for the key lock. the thing I tried all the combinations of buttons that are on the internet that enables/disables <kbd>Fn</kbd> key feature and they didn't work. Lately I tried my keyboard on another laptop and the <kbd>Fn</kbd> key was working fine just to make sure that the hardware button works fine. I also tried to uninstall the driver and reinstall it but didn't work. All I can think of right now is the Windows registry. For sure it contains a value for that my question is that how can I restore it to default so everything back to normal. I am running Windows 7.

Answer (score 0):

Enter the BIOS on the laptop you are having the problem on and change the default Fn key behavior to function keys.